# Fill and draw option

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a single option to set both the draw and the fill color of a TikZ node?

Something like:

```
\node[rectangle,drawandfill=red]{test};
```

The actual problem is the following: I have many adiacent rectangles node with different filling colors. Each rectangle has a different filling color.

Now I need to remove the tiny white border around each rectangle and I want that each rectangle has a drawing color equal to its filling color.

Since it would be a pain to rewrite `draw=<color name>` for every rectangle, I was hoping for a command like `fillanddrawn=<color name>` so that I could use some search and replace feature to add all the drawing colors at once.

Comment: If they are to be the same color, why not just `fill`? The only difference will be a `0.4pt` (with default line widths) difference in each dimension of the rectangle.

Comment: yes, that 0.4pt matters, it needs to be the same color of the filling. Anyway I think my question was too generic, I'll rephrase it.

Comment: `\tikzset{draw and fill/.style args={#1 and #2}{draw=#1,fill=#2}}` to be used as `draw and fill=blue and red`.

Comment: If your editor is a decent one, you can use it to do the search and replace in any case. For example, I'd search on `(fill=)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)` and replace with `\1\2, draw=\2` in Kile. The syntax will vary slightly depending on how your editor implements 'regular expressions' (complex search and replace patterns as opposed to plain words). If your editor can't do this, you are using the wrong editor ;).

Comment: Could you not just replace `fill=` with `fill, draw, ` throughout if there is not text in the nodes, as you say later?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define your own parameterized style to do this, with

```
\tikzset{drawandfill/.style={draw=#1,fill=#1}}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{drawandfill/.style={draw=#1,fill=#1}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle,drawandfill=red] at (0,0) {test};
  \node[rectangle,fill=red,draw=red] at (1,0) {test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The two nodes are identical:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that you want the fill and draw colour to be the same as you won't see anything!

Here's an example (the drawing colour is just give as the node colour and the fill colour is specified with `fill=...`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[blue,fill=red, rectangle]at (0,0){test};
  \node[blue,fill=blue, rectangle]at (1,0){test};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, my example is misleading. I have a jpeg into the node and no text.

Comment: Also, try `draw=red,fill=red` and you'll see that the text remains black.

Comment: @JennyC Then you probably don't need to specify the drawing colour at all?

Comment: @PaulGessler The text colour is given as an option to `\node` without any key. Please correct me if I am wrong but I believe that the `draw` option just tells tikz to draw the node, which it does by default anyway. 

Try `\node[draw,blue,fill=red, rectangle]at (0,0){test}; \node[draw,blue,fill=blue, rectangle]at (1,0){test};`. Both of them write blue text, not black.

Comment: @Andrew See the comments on the question, I need the 0.4pt draw line to be colored

Comment: @Andrew: Your last comment is not correct. The `draw` option in a node says to TikZ to color the node border with the specified color or in black, the default one. Both of your codes write blue text because of the following reason. Whenever you specify a color, that setting overrides the triple `draw`, `fill` and `text`. So, in code n.1, first you say `draw`, which makes the border in black, then you say `blue`, which makes the border, the background and its text blue and then you say `fill=red` which makes the background red. It's a miracle that TikZ does not complain with you ;)

Comment: I was forgetting: with colors, the order in which you specify the options matters. That's why `draw,blue,fill=red` makes `blue` cancel the previous `draw=black` and `fill=red` cancel the previous implicit setting `fill=blue`. Hope now it will be more clear.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino No reason for tikz to complain, is there? That is, I thought this was a feature since you can declare a colour and then change just one of the three elements rather than needing to specify all three when two are the same.

Comment: @cfr: Sure, TikZ does not complain for that and indeed it's a feature. Though, the point was related to users behaviour as I don't see any reasons for doing that. If you want blue border, red background and yellow text, is there any reason to override settings two times rather than go directly for the proper keys?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino No reason. But if you want blue border, blue background and yellow text, it saves typing ;).

Comment: @cfr: at the cost of clarity ;) No offense, but to me "saving keystrokes" is a completely non-sense metric. Codes should be clear as much as possible, for ourselves and for others, now and in 10 years. I prefer every time to add some comments or a much longer expression if this helps.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Agreed though I don't actually practise it all the time... However, mostly I find this useful if I want to override just one element in a common style.

Answer (score 3):

Use find/replace with Regular expressions (feature of editor, not of TeX) to replace any occurrence of ''fill=colorx,'' with ''fill=colorx,draw=colorx,''. In Winedt I just confirmed that searching for

```
fill=\(*\),
```

and replacing with

```
fill=\0,draw=\0,
```

will turn

```
\node[fill=red,rectangle]at (0,0){test};%
```

into

```
\node[fill=red,draw=red,rectangle]at (0,0){test};%
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to learn the regular expressions stuff asap :)

Comment: @JennyC Note that the syntax is editor dependent. (See my comment above re. Kile.)